# VueJs project - Vue-cli and npm run build

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

So I am currently building a vuejs application using Vue-cli and webpack. My site relies heavily on Firebase Database, so in my main.js file I have the following code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  ...layout,
  store,

  created () {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: MYKEY,
      authDomain: 'foo.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://foo.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'foo'
    })
  }
```

This works great, however, I would like to use a different Firebase Database when going live (Production).

Therefore when I run 'npm run build' I would like to change the firebase.initializeApp code to something like this:

```
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: MYKEY-PRODUCTION,
      authDomain: 'production.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://production.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'production'
    })
```

What is the correct way to do this with VUE-CLI.

I look forward to your help folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the config folder situated at the root of your project. You should see two files : dev.env.js and prod.env.js

In those files you can define variables. So define a firebaseConfig variable in prod.env.js :

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: MYKEY-PRODUCTION,
    authDomain: 'production.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://production.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'production'
  }
}
```

And do the same in dev.env.js with your 'foo' project.

Then in the vuejs component, write :

```
firebase.initializeApp(process.env.firebaseConfig)
```

As a result, when you run **npm run dev**, firebaseConfig will have the content of your **dev**.env.js file.

And when you run **npm run build** ... the content of **build**.env.js

Answer (score 0):

[Myfirebase](https://github.com/myfirebase/myfirebase) is a good starting point for using firebase with vuejs, it does a lot of pre-configuration for you behind the scenes.